# Crawler not saving cookies

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawling

We have a website built on asp.net with forms and windows authentication that we try to index with Sharepoint 2013. According to the logs the crawling user can login to the site but the sessioncookie is not persistent. So the next request does not include the cookies in the request headers according to Fiddler.

I cant find any information about this, is there some limitaions that the crawler does not save cookies?

We are using the option "use the default content access account" for authentication in the rule-setting. Is it different when using formsauth-option instead? I dont have access to the crawling server myself... So I cant make these small tests.